# How to do late binding in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, late-binding

I have a function that creates an email via VBA.

I made this through Excel 2016. When some of my colleagues try to use it there an error of missing references (Outlook Library 16.0).

I looked in the internet for solutions and found the best is Late Binding. I have read about it but I don't understand how to make it work in the following example code.

```
Sub EscalateCase(what_address As String, subject_line As String, email_body As String)
    
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
    olMail.To = what_address
    olMail.Subject = subject_line
    olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    olMail.HTMLBody = email_body
    olMail.Send
        
End Sub
```

Comment: change `Dim olApp As Outlook.Application` to `Dim olApp As Object`

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation

Answer (score 14):

This is early binding:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
```

And this is late binding:

```
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Late binding does not require a reference to *Outlook Library 16.0* whereas early binding does. However, note that late binding is a bit slower and you won't get intellisense for that object.

Answer (score 6):

As Callum pointed out, late binding involves changing your application reference to an object and not setting a reference to the library.

Without a reference Excel doesn't know anything about Outlook until runtime.  This also means that not only will intellisense not work, the constant names for values in Outlook won't work either.

e.g. In Outlooks Immediate window if you type `Application.CreateItem(` you'll get a whole load of item types pop up to choose from.  `olContactItem` for instance.

Excel hasn't a clue what `olContactItem` means - it's an Outlook constant that only Outlook or an application with a reference to Outlook understands.

In Outlooks immediate window type `?olContactItem` and it will return `2`.  That's the number you need to use instead of the constant name.

So your code changes from
`Application.CreateItem(olContactItem)` to `olApp.CreateItem(2)`

You need to do this throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation I generally define the constant globally in a module like this, that way you preserve the descriptive value of the variable.

Public Const olFormatHTML = 2