# Excel VBA Error "user-defined type not defined" with Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am using Office 2016 in my computer and I have a VBA code that sends Email to so mail lists in the file. Every time I want to send the Emails automatically with my CommandButton, I get the error massage:  "user-defined type not defined".
I made some research in the web and I found out that there is a solution:
VB Editor ----> Tools ----> Referenced ----> Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

**But**
the next time I open the file the same error runs again and again and again. Can someone find me solution that will be permanent? I Don't know what to do more then I already did.

```
Public Sub sendMail()
    Call ini_set

    If mail_msg.Cells(200, 200) = 1 Then
        lr = main_dist.Cells(main_dist.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To lr

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
            Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
            mail_msg.Visible = True
            mailSub = mail_msg.Range("B1")
            mailBody = mail_msg.Range("B2")
            mail_msg.Visible = False
            Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
            Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(main_dist.Cells(i, 5))
            recptOL.Type = olTo

            tempPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & main_dist.Cells(i, 4) & ".xlsm"

            With miOL
                .Subject = mailSub
                .Body = mailBody
                .Attachments.Add tempPath
                .send

            End With
            Set applOL = Nothing
            Set miOL = Nothing
            Set recptOL = Nothing
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True


        Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the problem based on the VB Editor:

```
Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
```

Comment: Usually when you add a reference in a document, it should stay there forever. Are you sure you are saving your document after adding the reference?

Comment: You can use late binding also so that you don't have to reference the library. So `Dim applOL As Outlook.Application` will become `Dim applOL As object` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do late binding in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056390/how-to-do-late-binding-in-vba)

Comment: @CallumDA -- so, if someone mentions a potential fix that could have been mentioned elsewhere at some point, that instantly makes it a duplicate question, even though it wasn't asked in the original question?  *sigh*  I don't see _any_ terms from the "possible duplicate" in this question.  ...I'm not saying this is a great question, but it is **not** a duplicate, at least not of your example.

Comment: @ashleedawg, put it this way. If OP follows the link they will find out how to early bind and late bind correctly. One of these must be acceptable to OP because there is simply no other way. *Duplicate questions* doesn't mean the questions need to look identical, but it does mean that the answer to this question already exists elsewhere on the site. By this definition, I do consider this a duplicate.

Comment: @CallumDA -- [A question should only be closed if its an **exact** duplicate of another question.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/553/) … [There’s often **benefit to having multiple subtle variants** of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they’re looking for … in the same ballpark as a previous question, but have subtle **differences that may make them legitimately standalone questions**.](http://stackoverflow.blog/handling-duplicate-questions) …

Comment: @CallumDA -- …… [If understanding **why** the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions **aren't** duplicates, **merely related**.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844) … ["possible duplicate notification" warns you that someone dumb enough may misread your question in a really weird way … ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476) ... w/e it's not even my question, I just see some pretty silly flags sometimes from people who could instead just vote down and move along.

Comment: @ashleedawg, I read those articles. They back up my assertions in many places but comments aren’t the place for this so take it to meta if you really want to seek validation in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, you can edit your code like below (see three commented lines) and should be able to run without references. **I am assuming that the code is correct otherwise and it is providing intended results**

```
Public Sub sendMail()
    Call ini_set

    If mail_msg.Cells(200, 200) = 1 Then
        lr = main_dist.Cells(main_dist.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To lr

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Dim applOL As Object       '\\Outlook.Application
            Dim miOL As Object         '\\Outlook.MailItem
            Dim recptOL As Object      '\\Outlook.Recipient
            mail_msg.Visible = True
            mailSub = mail_msg.Range("B1")
            mailBody = mail_msg.Range("B2")
            mail_msg.Visible = False
            Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
            Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add(main_dist.Cells(i, 5))
            recptOL.Type = olTo

            tempPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & main_dist.Cells(i, 4) & ".xlsm"

            With miOL
                .Subject = mailSub
                .Body = mailBody
                .Attachments.Add tempPath
                .send

            End With
            Set applOL = Nothing
            Set miOL = Nothing
            Set recptOL = Nothing
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True


        Next i
End Sub
```

Late binding can help in some other cases as well especially if there are several users and they are having different setups with respect to software versions!