# VBA code to paste to Word from Excel runs on some PCs and returns error 4198 on other

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been tasked with writing a simple tool that takes a set of tables from Excel and pastes them into a new Word document to generate a summary report. I have written this using a function to do the actual copying and pasting, and run it on 4 PCs. Two run it without errors; two are throwing a 4198 error on the line `AppWord.Selection.Paste` in the function (end of the code)

I tried using a different approach by referencing the document instead, but that failed to paste the content. I am now thoroughly stuck, and would appreciate any help with regards to making the code run consistently across PCs/Office versions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteToWord()

    Dim AppWord As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strPathSep As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'establish errorhandler  

    'find filepath and define document name including full path
    strFolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strPathSep = Application.PathSeparator
    strFileName = strFolderPath & strPathSep & "Rapport" & " " & Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date)

    'check if report has already been made for today
    If Not Dir(strFileName & ".docx", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        If MsgBox("En rapport er allerede blevet lavet for i dag. Ønsker du at overskrive rapporten?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            MsgBox "Makroen er stoppet og rapporten er ikke blevet overskrevet"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If

    'initialize Word, create and save document

    Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    AppWord.Visible = False 'hides Word
    Set WordDoc = AppWord.Documents.Add
    WordDoc.SaveAs2 (strFileName)

    'optimize
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'function to copy into document
    'syntax for function CopyPaste is codename for sheet, first range in table, last range in table, AppWord which is the reference to the Word Object
    CopyPaste Sheet15, "H12", "L24", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet19, "H12", "L26", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet11, "I15", "M36", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet12, "G1", "H29", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet16, "G1", "H22", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet13, "H12", "L24", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet14, "G2", "K7", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet17, "G3", "K15", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet20, "G4", "K11", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet21, "J3", "P10", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet22, "E1", "G15", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "K2", "R16", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "K22", "R36", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "K42", "R55", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "V2", "Y16", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "V22", "Y36", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "V42", "Y55", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet23, "AA5", "AE7", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "K2", "R16", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "K22", "R36", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "K42", "R55", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "V2", "Y16", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "V22", "Y36", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "V42", "Y55", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet24, "AA5", "AE7", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet25, "N2", "R21", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet27, "N2", "R21", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet26, "N2", "R21", AppWord
    CopyPaste Sheet28, "N2", "R21", AppWord

    GoTo SubSucess 'included to skip the error handler

    '''''''''''''''  
    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "En ukendt fejl er opstået. Makroen afslutter, men rapporten kan være ufuldendt."
    GoTo EndSub
    '''''''''''''''' 
    SubSucess:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "Rapport genereret og gemt" 'msgbox to confirm the sub has run without errors

    EndSub:
    'close and exit
    WordDoc.Close
    AppWord.Quit
    Set AppWord = Nothing

    'restore optimize
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
End Sub

Function CopyPaste(ByVal wsSheet As Worksheet, ByVal rngRange1 As String,  
  ByVal rngRange2 As String, ByRef AppWord As Object)

    'function to paste range as picture to word document
    'inputs: sheet = sheet codename, rng1 and 2 are the range that contain the table and AppWord is a reference to the word object from the subroutine

    wsSheet.Range(rngRange1, rngRange2).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    AppWord.Selection.Paste 'paste in active word document
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard
    AppWord.Selection.TypeParagraph 'create a space between pasted table
End Function
```

Comment: Does it fail on first time the funcion `CopyPaste` is called? Are all PC's same version of Office?

Comment: The error came after the function had run successfully a few times. The code is written in 64 bit Office and the error came from the PCs that run 32 bit Office.

Comment: My guess is that the PCs have (possibly slightly) different installations/versions of MS Word. You're using early binding in your VBA code. I suggest changing to late binding, which should solve the issue. Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056493/4717755) and [this](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/EarlyLateBinding.html)

Comment: Hi Peter. I changed the code so both the application and document are declared as objects and set later. However it still throws an error on 32 bit after a 1 or more iterations of the function.

Comment: What is the text for the error code?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is due to a "race condition" - the code is executing faster than Word can process the paste operation, so it's unable to accept a new one. You might try sticking a `DoEvents` in there...

Comment: Hi Cindy. I looked into DoEvents, and included the statement at the end of the function, which unfortunately didn't solve the issue. Were you thinking about a different way of using it? With regards to text, I can't produce the error on my own PC but think that it simply stated that the command failed.

Comment: I tried including a wait statement, which did not work either. However I ran it successfully on a 32 bit Office install, so that's not the difference. The computers all run Win 10 and there's no obvious pattern in when it works and when it doesn't.