# Row.delete from Access vba using late binding

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access programm that opens an Excel and deletes it's first row with `row.delete(1)`. But my problem is that I have to perform this task using late binding because this programm it's executed in different versions of Access so I cannot simply add the Excel Library reference to my Access to execute this method.

Is there anyway to perform this `row.delete(1)` with late binding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056390/how-to-do-late-binding-in-vba. Yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do late binding in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056390/how-to-do-late-binding-in-vba)